# UIProgressView like control for Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, progress-bar

I am looking for an control having the look and feel of a UIProgressView but on Mac.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/progress_in_bar.jpg

I am wondering if there is already something similar or if I have to develop something from scratch.

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa has a class named [`NSProgressIndicator`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that can be used as a progress bar, either determinate or indeterminate. Take a look at the [Human Interface Guidelines document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGControls/XHIGControls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TPXREF106).